# LINQ 2 SQL Nested Table Insert Error makes NO SENSE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below LINQ method that I use to create the empty `EmploymentPLan`.  After that I simply `UPDATE`.  For some reason this works perfectly for myself but for my users they are getting the following error -->

`The target table 'dbo.tblEmploymentPrevocServices' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.`

**The strangest part of this is that you can see the the below Generated SQL that they DO, in fact, contain INTO clauses.  WTH???**

This application is a WinForm app that connects to a local SQL 2005 Express database that is a part of a Merge Replication topology.  This is an INTERNAL App only installed through ClickOnce.

---

```
public static Guid InsertEmptyEmploymentPlan(int planID, string user)
    {
        using (var context = MatrixDataContext.Create())
        {                               
            var empPlan = new tblEmploymentQuestionnaire
                                  {
                                      PlanID = planID,
                                      InsertDate = DateTime.Now,
                                      InsertUser = user,
                                      tblEmploymentJobDevelopmetService = new tblEmploymentJobDevelopmetService(),
                                      tblEmploymentPrevocService = new tblEmploymentPrevocService()
                                  };

                context.tblEmploymentQuestionnaires.InsertOnSubmit(empPlan);

                context.SubmitChanges();

            return empPlan.EmploymentQuestionnaireID;
        }
    }
```

---

After further review I noticed that the, previously, accepted solution did not truly apply as `Auto-Sync` was **ALREADY** set to never for all **ID Columns**.

Anyone have any other ideas?  Thanks

---

He is the generated SQL.  I know it is long but I am just at a loss.  This is ALL generated by the single above Method.

```
DECLARE @output TABLE([EmploymentPrevocID] UniqueIdentifier)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEmploymentPrevocServices]([AvgRatePay], [AvgHoursWeek], [SettingID], [PrevocGoal], [SkillsTaught], [SkillsLearned], [AnticipatedTransitionPlans], [AnticipatedEndDate], [RatioID])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[EmploymentPrevocID] INTO @output
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)
SELECT [EmploymentPrevocID] FROM @output
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p3: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p4: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p5: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p6: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p7: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p8: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.4926

DECLARE @output TABLE([JobDevelopmentServicesID] UniqueIdentifier)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEmploymentJobDevelopmetServices]([TypeWorkDesired], [PreferredWorkHoursID], [NeedEmploymentServices], [DVRProvidingServices], [DVRCurrentReferral], [PaidCoachingHoursID], [PlanSegregatedToIntegrated], [RoleResponseJobDeveloper], [RoleResponseMember], [RoleResponseWWCTeam], [PlanDVRToWWCFund], [PlanReducePaidSupports])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[JobDevelopmentServicesID] INTO @output
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11)
SELECT [JobDevelopmentServicesID] FROM @output
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p2: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p3: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p4: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p5: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p6: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p7: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p8: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p9: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p10: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p11: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.4926

DECLARE @output TABLE([EmploymentQuestionnaireID] UniqueIdentifier)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblEmploymentQuestionnaire]([PlanID], [CommunityJob], [PrevocServices], [JobDevelopmentServices], [PrevocServicesID], [JobDevelopmentServicesID], [InsertUser], [InsertDate], [UpdateUser], [UpdateDate], [TransitionedPrevocToIntegrated], [EmploymentServiceMatchPref])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[EmploymentQuestionnaireID] INTO @output
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11)
SELECT [EmploymentQuestionnaireID] FROM @output
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [37017]
-- @p1: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [False]
-- @p2: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [False]
-- @p3: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [False]
-- @p4: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [a3674e69-9b78-df11-b74e-001e0bd023bc]
-- @p5: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [a4674e69-9b78-df11-b74e-001e0bd023bc]
-- @p6: Input VarChar (Size = 9; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [pschaller]
-- @p7: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [6/15/2010 11:31:13 AM]
-- @p8: Input VarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p9: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p10: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p11: Input Bit (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.4926
```

Comment: Would the generated SQL help at all to trouble shoot this?  I ask because it is SO LONG and I'd hate to turn away potential answers based on Question Length...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this apply to you?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961073

> FIX: Error message when you run a DML
>   statement in a LINQ to SQL application
>   in SQL Server 2008: "The target table
>   '' of the DML statement
>   cannot have any enabled triggers if
>   the statement contains an OUTPUT
>   clause without INTO clause"

Comment: Wow, I don't know how or why but this does, in fact, fix my error.  Thanks.  Easiest 200 you'll probably every get!! :)

Comment: So where's my "selected answer love?"  I need those 200 points to buy my daughter a new pair of shoes  :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error seems pretty clear, and makes sense. Some thoughts:

- are your users using *your* db, or is it installed locally? Maybe they're using SQL Server 2008 (or R2), and maybe something changed?
- are you sure your db setup is the same as theirs? maybe you have your own copy of the tables (`SomeName\MyTable` instead of `dbo.MyTable`), and your copy doesn't have the triggers?
- have they got replication enabled? (which can work via triggers) Indexed views? Partitioning? etc

Comment: 1) this is internal only so they are all on 2005 express though now that I think of it I can't guaruntee they are all on the same sp#.
2) Same as #1
3) Yes, these are apart of Merge Replication.  
I noticed in the Connection String Advanced options there is a Replication setting that I have no idea what it does...

Answer (score 4):

Your database has a trigger that interferes with the OUTPUT clause of the generated sql.

Since the trigger is probably not something that can be removed, you need to instead stop the generated sql from having an OUTPUT clause.

To do that, set the `AutoSync` property of each column in the table to `Never`.  This can be done in the LinqToSql designer.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.autosync(v=VS.100).aspx

After doing that, there is a new problem.  Your method wants to return the generated ID, but the generated ID is not longer automatically fetched for you.  You must alter the method to query for the newly inserted record.

Comment: @David B:  Sorry to take the answer away.  Totally my fault for 'preemptively' marking an answer with out testing it.  Unfortunately, `Auto-Sync` is already set to Never for ID Columns.

Comment: Hey, no problem. If auto-sync isn't creating the OUTPUT clause, you need to look at your generate sql (by using the sql profiler, or DataContext.Log property) to see what that OUTPUT clause is trying to do. Then you can shutdown whatever feature of LinqToSql is causing it to be generated. (although if auto-sync is off, I can't imagine what purpose returning data from the db could serve.)  (also - with autosync off, it casts your method which returns the generated id in a suspicious light).

Comment: Could it be the `Auto Generated Value`?  That is set to `True` for all three tables Primary ID's which 'seems' to correlate with the OUTPUT's in the above SQL statements.

Comment: AutoGeneratedValue=True leads to IsDbGenerated=True  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdbgenerated.aspx

gotta think on what to do...

Comment: actually, has the error message changed?  those output clauses have into clauses.